# Comparing characteristics of accessing class properties in C# via a static generic class and static class with ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, generics, reflection, concurrentdictionary

I'm using C#, and I have two approaches for accessing class properties: through `Entity<Unit>.PropertyAccessors` and `EntityManager.PropertyAccessor<Unit>()`. Both options provide access to class metadata for working with properties. I'm interested in the differences in their performance, memory usage, thread safety, and other relevant aspects.

What are the key distinctions between `Entity<Unit>.PropertyAccessors` and `EntityManager.PropertyAccessor<Unit>()` in terms of performance, memory usage, thread safety, and other critical aspects? Is there a preferred option in each of these categories? Are there any potential pitfalls or gotchas that I should be aware of when using either of these implementations?

I'm using a ThreadSafeDictionary with `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>` under the hood.

Below is the code I'm using for a more detailed context:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

internal sealed record PropertyAccessor(string Name, Func<object, object> Get, Action<object, object> Set);

internal static class Entity<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyAccessor> PropertyAccessors => LazyPropertyAccessors.Value;

    private static readonly Lazy<IList<PropertyAccessor>> LazyPropertyAccessors = new(() => GetPropertiesAccessor(typeof(TEntity)));

    private static IList<PropertyAccessor> GetPropertiesAccessor(IReflect type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
            .Select(GetEntityProperty)
            .ToArray();
    }

    private static PropertyAccessor GetEntityProperty(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return new PropertyAccessor(property.Name, property.GetGetMethod().BuildGetAccessor(), property.GetSetMethod().BuildSetAccessor());
    }
}

internal static class EntityManager
{
    private static readonly IThreadSafeDictionary<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyAccessor>> EntitiesPropertiesAccessor;

    static EntityManager()
    {
        EntitiesPropertiesAccessor = new ThreadSafeDictionary<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyAccessor>>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PropertyAccessor> PropertiesAccessor<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        return EntitiesPropertiesAccessor.GetOrAdd(typeof(TEntity), GetPropertiesAccessor);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PropertyAccessor> GetPropertiesAccessor(IReflect type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
            .Select(GetEntityProperty)
            .ToArray();
    }

    private static PropertyAccessor GetEntityProperty(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return new PropertyAccessor(property.Name, property.GetGetMethod().BuildGetAccessor(), property.GetSetMethod().BuildSetAccessor());
    }
}


public static class ReflectionTypeExtensions
{
    public static Func<object, object> BuildGetAccessor(this MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(method));

        var declaringType = method.DeclaringType;

        if (declaringType == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(method.DeclaringType));

        var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

        var getter = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(
            Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(obj, declaringType), method), typeof(object)),
            obj);

        return getter.Compile();
    }

    public static Action<object, object> BuildSetAccessor(this MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(method));

        var declaringType = method.DeclaringType;

        if (declaringType == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(method.DeclaringType));

        var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(obj, declaringType),
                method,
                Expression.Convert(value, method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType)),
            obj,
            value);

        return expr.Compile();
    }
}
```

Additional information:

1. I haven't tried BenchmarkDotNet yet.
2. I'm interested in how exactly memory allocation for static shared classes would be handled. Does this approach have advantages over a static class with a static ConcurrentDictionary?
3. `IEntity` is simply a label for entity models from the database

Here's his code:

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; set; }
}
```

`Unit` is just a model of an entity from a database that has no logic, and consists only of properties
Here's his code:

```cs
public class Unit : IEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

4. This code is intended to get all the properties of the entity model so that copying can be implemented later. The static, Lazy and ConcurrentDictionary mechanisms are added to avoid using reflection and expression tree for the same types every time.

So I will shorten my question, how will memory handling be handled for static generic classes? Will there be an advantage in this case on one static class with a static buffer? Are there any potential pitfalls or issues I should be aware of when using a static generic class?

Comment: Have you tried running it and using something like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)?

Comment: it's impossible to provide a simple answer for such a generic questions. Please be specific about your concerns, and try to measure it in your real app directly. Chances are you're just optimizing something without any need to do so.

Comment: What are you really doing? It looks like something involving reflection, and I hope that is some rare, highly specialized case. And if so, do you really care about performance? Static properties are usually thread safe, but always check the documentation to make sure. In entity framework there are sometimes different ways to access the same thing, so I would not *expect* much difference, but benchmark if you want to know for sure.